# Plugin showing fatal error while running a loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a plugin and it is showing fatal error when I am running a for-each loop as an activation hook but when i run the code without the loop it works fine.

Blew is the code i am using:

```
function wp_create_table_insert_data()
{
    global $wpdb;

$state_name= ["Andaman and Nicobar Islands","Andhra Pradesh","Assam","Bihar","Chandigarh","Chhattisgarh","Dadra and Nagar Haveli","Daman and Diu","Delhi","Goa","Gujarat","Haryana","Himachal Pradesh","Jammu and Kashmir","Jharkhand","Karnataka","Kerala","Lakshadweep","Madhya Pradesh","Maharashtra","Manipur","Meghalaya","Mizoram","Nagaland","Odisha","Puducherry","Punjab","Rajasthan","Sikkim","Tamil Nadu","Telangana","Tripura","Uttar Pradesh","Uttarakhand","West Bengal"];


    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'state';

foreach ($state_name as $row){
    $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('state_name' => $row));
}
}
```

Comment: What does it say besides fatal error?

Comment: Hi, it could be that in your database, the table `state` may have `id` column that is not set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Are you getting a duplicate primary key error?

Comment: @Rimble Nothing it is just telling Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.

Comment: @PaulJanubas I have auto increment on the table.